# Try/except not catching errors in compiled Python

Tags: python, exception, compilation, try-catch, except

I've got a bit of code involving Try and Except clauses. When I just run it in console in IDLE, it works perfectly, and never crashes. However, when I compile it is fails to catch errors, so the program crashes, and this is driving me mad!

The code is:

```
if self.height == 6:
    try:
        libtcod.path_compute(minimap[self.mapx][self.mapy].path3,self.x+60, self.y+60,target_x+60, target_y+60)
        stepx, stepy = libtcod.path_get(minimap[self.mapx][self.mapy].path3, 0)
        dx = stepx - self.x - 60
        dy = stepy - self.y - 60
    except:
        success = False
```

I'm using the libtcod library. It's the stepx/stepy bit it sometimes fails on, and the thing is, I *know* it can sometimes fail on that bit; it just doesn't catch it! I've tried having it print a message before/after the stepx section, and it'll print the first part, but not the latter. There's a multitude of options that can lead to success = False, and this only one, and then later I deal with what happens if success == False (it's for a game, testing if a foe can path to you, and if not, then it tries something else). I have no idea why it can catch it when uncompiled but fails totally when compiled. Can someone please explain this to me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say it "crashes", what exactly happens? Also, what do you mean by "compile"? If you just run the script from the command line (python foo.py), does it work?

Comment: Windows encounters an error, without a console message even if I enable console, it and dies. This is using py2exe; I'm on Windows, and I'm not sure how to do the command line version. If I choose just the "Run Module" option in IDLE (I'm still somewhat new to Python) then it handles the try/except perfectly.

Comment: I've used that library before. Since the python version is a wrapper around a C++ library, it will occasionally run into segfaults that aren't raised as a python error properly. Is that what's happening here?

Comment: Ah, no worries - I've found a way to solve it, since I've found that function actually returns False if it can't find a path, so I don't need to try try/except. Thanks anyway everyone!

Comment: So… is it actually raising an exception in IDLE or was your entire question wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Try checking all the arguments that you pass to the libtcod function that crashes your program (in this case `libtcod.path_get`). Libtcod will often segfault when you pass in incorrect arguments rather than raising a nice error message, I had the same problem with the field of view toolkit.

If these values are different in your version "compiled" with py2exe for some reason then that could explain why it only crashes sometimes.

This part looks problematic:

```
minimap[self.mapx][self.mapy]
```

If you have a nested array like so:

```
minimap = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
           [5, 6, 7, 8],
           [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Then to refer to the item at position (x, y) you must use `minimap[y][x]`

Edit:

`libtcod.path_get`'s first argument should be a map used for path-finding, which is returned by `path_new_using_map` or `dijkstra_new`. You don't need a separate map for each square in your map. I think you should read the documentation a little more thoroughly:
 http://doryen.eptalys.net/data/libtcod/doc/1.5.0/index.html